# Dynatable Implementation

Tags: javascript, json

I am attempting to learn some jQuery and javascript and have a neat project to try. It involves pulling data from a JSON file and displaying it in a table form, based on date. I've found Dynatable which seems to do what I want, but I keep getting an "unexpected end of JSON input" error. I am using the same syntax as in the example given on the Dynatabe page, but it does not return any records. Any help would be appreciated, as I'm sure I'm missing something simple. The JSON file is named json-records.json

```js
[
  {
    "band": "Weezer",
    "song": "GA Scorcho"
  },
  {
    "band": "Chevelle",
    "song": "Family System"
  },
]
```

```html
<html>

<head>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="./jspkg-archive/jquery.dynatable.js"></script>
 <script src="json-records.json"></script>
 <style src="./jspkg-archive/jquery.dynatable.css"></style>
</head>

<body>
<table id="my-final-table">
  <thead>
    <th>Band</th>
    <th>Song</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready( function(){
 $('#my-final-table').dynatable();
});


var $records = $('#json-records'),
    myRecords = JSON.parse($records.text());
$('#my-final-table').dynatable({
  dataset: {
    records: myRecords
  }
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a stray ',' in your JSON file

```
[
  {
    "band": "Weezer",
    "song": "GA Scorcho"
  },
  {
    "band": "Chevelle",
    "song": "Family System"
  }, <--- Here
]
```

Comment: Thanks!. I fixed that error, but it still will not work. When I use a debugger, it seems to hang on this line                                                               myRecords = JSON.parse($records.text());

Comment: I was looking through the documentation for dynatable and see you're doing their examples. The example you want to look at is the AJAX example. If you already have the data, and want to make a table out of it then do AJAX. If you have a table and want to get the data out of it, then use JSON.parse()

Comment: That makes sense! I'll try it. Thanks so much!!